# Fibonacci number program crashes with exit code 139

Tags: c

I am testing edge cases in my Fibonacci number program. It runs fine if the input value for first variable is `999999` or below. It crashes when the value is anything bigger. I am already using `long int` somewhere, really no clue what am I doing wrong.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long ft(long num, int m) {
    long arr[num];
    int i;
    int j = 0;
    i = 3;
    arr[0] = 0;
    arr[1] = 1;
    arr[2] = 1;
    while (i <= num && j != 1) {
        arr[i] = 0;

        if ((arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2]) < m) {
            arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];
        } else {
            arr[i] = (arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2]) % m;
        }
        if (arr[i] == 1 && arr[i - 1] == 1 && arr[i - 2] == 0)
            j = 1;

        i++;
    }

    if (i < num)
        return arr[num % (i - 3)];
    else
        return arr[i - 1];
}

int main() {
    long n = 0;
    int m = 0;
    scanf("%ld %d", &n, &m);
    printf("%ld", ft(n, m));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If `i==num`, then `arr[i]` is one past the end of the array.

Comment: Why does code return a `long` or use `long arr[num];`?  Every value in the array `arr[]` is < `m`, an `int` due to `% m`.  IAC, only `int arr[3]` needed.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? `ft` only returns a single number, but in the `i<num` case I cannot figure out what it represents.

Answer (score 2):

That's too much stack. Please allocate arr with `malloc()` and please check for allocation failures. Don't forget to free `arr`.

```
long *arr = malloc(sizeof(long) * (size_t)(num + 1));
if (!arr) return -1; // Error
//...
long r;
if (i < num) r= arr[num%(i-3)];
else r= arr[i-1];
free(arr);
return r;
```

Comment: @JohnKugelman: I didn't try to understand his algorithm. It doesn't look like the same Fibonacci I know.

Answer (score 0):

Your program computes Fibonacci numbers modulo a given number.

The reason it crashes for values above `999999` is you allocate a variable length array of `long` with automatic storage (aka *on the stack*), that exceeds the available space in this segment (4 or 8 MB). Your program has undefined behavior and causes a **stack overflow**.

You should instead allocate this array from the heap with `malloc` or `calloc` and free it before leaving the function.

Note also these other problems:

- `arr` should have a length of `num + 1` because you store the result in `arr[num]`.
- the result is incorrect for `num == 0` and for `m == 1`.
- the function has undefined behavior for `m == 0`.
- negative values of `m` and `num` should return an error result such as `-1`.
- the test for cycle detection can be simplified.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

long ft(long num, int m) {
    long *arr;
    int i;
    long res;

    if (m < 0 || num < 0 || (arr = calloc(sizeof(*arr), num + 1)) == NULL)
        return -1;

    if (m == 1)
        return 0;

    arr[0] = 0;
    arr[1] = 1;
    arr[2] = 1;
    res = arr[num];

    for (i = 3; i <= num; i++) {
        res = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];
        if (res >= m)
            res -= m;

        arr[i] = res;
        if (res == 0 && arr[i - 1] == 1) { // handle cycle
            res = arr[num % i];
            break;
        }
    }
    free(arr);
    return res;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    long n, n2;
    int m = 0;
    char *p;

    if (argc > 1) {  // command line arguments: start[..end] [mod]
        n = n2 = strtol(argv[0], &p, 0);
        if (*p == '.' && p[1] == '.')
            n2 = strtol(p + 2, NULL, 0);
        if (argc > 2)
            m = strtol(argv[0], NULL, 0);
    } else {
        if (scanf("%ld %d", &n, &m) != 2)
            return 1;
        n2 = n;
    }
    while (n <= n2)
        printf("%ld\n", ft(n++, m));
    return 0;
}
```